# dts out of order issue while clipping from m3u8 file

Tags: ffmpeg

Ran this command to clip from m3u8 based on start time in seconds and clip duration:

```
ffmpeg -i master.m3u8 -loglevel info -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy -a codec copy -ss 240 -t 60 clip.mp4
```

Because of DTS out of order error, I am unable to clip the required video segment.Output from the command.:

```
//reads initial ts files

[mpegts @ 0x207ab80] DTS 136803 < 10924791 out of order
[hls,applehttp @ 0x20603c0] DTS 136803 < 10924791 out of order
//after this, command continues reading rest of the ts files and "dts out of order" issue is printed multiple times.
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @T-Me because of DTS out of order issue, I am unable to clip the segment from the m3u8 video stream